# Front-end Performance and mapping services: Google Maps vs competition

Tags: performance, google-maps, canvas, openstreetmap

With the risk of being flagged "chatty" question, I would like to analyze the technical advantages and disadvantages of using Google Maps vs other services (like for example OpenStreetMaps+Leaflet).

One thing I observed is that Google Maps suffers from performance problems, which increase when there's lots going on in the map (many markers). I also noticed that each service is based on a different front-end technology: svg, canvas, images ..

I am building a project which will make a somewhat heavy use of maps so I would like to have your opinion on which service would be better to go with.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a good answer to this question. Both mapping services addressed by you can be used by multiple front ends. For example both [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) (and every other library that is able to show *tiles*) can show both OSM and Google Maps tiles so there is nothing to compare here.

One of the real advantages of OpenStreetMap is that you are not limited to a specific data representation. OSM data is free available and consequently a OSM-based map can use any technology you want. There are already [lots of different OSM based services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_based_Services) and  [rendering libraries](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering#Libraries) / [client renderers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles#Client_.2F_Renderer) available using very different technologies to show the map.